# Javafx Hyperlink parameters on action

Tags: dynamic, hyperlink, javafx, actionevent

Thank you for reading my question and apologies for the noobness

I am writing my first JavaFX application in which I have an array of hyperlinks which have latitude longitude (e.g. "42N 7E") in the text value of the hyperlink which is being updated every second from another Thread and updates the hyperlink text in the Main Thread.  (This works fine)

```
public static void setPosLatLong(String posLatLong, int SID) {
    Main.posLatLong[SID].setText(posLatLongValue);
}
```

I am trying to use the value in the hyperlink text when clicking on the hyperlink to dynamically change the destination URL with the latest latlong values... but I get the error 'local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final'

```
int SID = 'id of the hyperlink corresponding to a machine'

posLatLong[SID] = new Hyperlink();
posLatLong[SID].setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    getHostServices().showDocument("http://maps.google.com/maps?z=17&q=" + posLatLong[SID].getText());
});
```

I have tried all kinds of ways to get around this but I am shamefully stuck.  If anyone could point me in the right direction so that the last updated value in the hyperlink array is passed as a parameter when opening the browser it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to find a solution myself so I'll post it in case it could be useful to someone

```
            posLatLong[i].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    String eventLatLong = ""; 
                    Object source = event.getSource();
                    if (source instanceof Hyperlink) {
                        Hyperlink link = (Hyperlink) source;
                        eventLatLong = link.getText();
                    }

                    getHostServices().showDocument("http://maps.google.com/maps?z=17&q=" + eventLatLong    );
                }
            });
```

Tada !